# Cron user account to set up cron job for Laravel task scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a laravel app installed on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu server. I know I can create a cron entry by using the following command `crontab -e` to open a cron file and set up the task scheduler:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/mylaravelproject && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

My question is under which user account do I create this cron entry? Should it be the root account or my user account?

Please note I added myself as owner of the laravel project directory using the following command

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/mylaravelproject
```

Comment: You can use any user which has permission to access your code directory, that can be your user or root.